# Can't run node.js debug from eclipse using chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to run node.js debug under Ubuntu with Eclipse: 3.7.1, Chromium JS Debugger 0.3 and node.js 4.12 (stable).

I installed and configured debug as described on https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger.

I run my node app with --debug, then I run debug in eclipse, I see it connects to the debug port but then it crashes with message "**An internal error occurred during: "Launching Node 5858".
java.lang.NullPointerException**"

Communication looks like:

> Received from Chrome: Type: connect V8-Version: 3.1.8.26
>   Protocol-Version: 1 Embedding-Host: node v0.4.12 Content-Length: 0
>
> end of message
>
> Sent to Chrome:
>
> end of message
>
> Content-Length:46
>
> {"seq":3,"type":"request","command":"version"}
>
> end of message
>
> Received from Chrome:
>
> Content-Length: 135
>
> {"seq":2,"request_seq":3,"type":"response","command":"version","success":true,"body":{"V8Version":"3.1.8.26"},"refs":[],"running":true}
>
> end of message

Comment: Any follow up on this? I currently experience the same problem, while it has worked fine for months. Obviously I did something, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what. Maybe your solution can help others figure their similar issue out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should report the problem, since it deals with exception (clearly a bug).

Here's instruction: http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/HowToReportProblem

It also covers how to get the the NullPointerException stacktrace which is probably the most valuable piece of data here.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebStorm(phpStorm) and node.js debug extension